# Converted PDF should be saved on server side, not downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

The issue is that a converted PDF is downloaded by the client. I need the PDF to be saved on server side and sent by mail. 
I am using jsPDF and html2canvas for converting HTML to PDF.

Comment: Since you imply you can do things server-side, why not a simple web service that accepts the PDF and email, etc. in a POST and builds and sends the email? Just use the client side to generate and POST it back.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that jsPDF is not the proper tool for your task. First line at Github is "Client-side JavaScript PDF generation for everyone" which says it all.

To let the server create a PDF, you need a tool which renders the HTML result and creates a PDF from it. Maybe a MS Word or OpenDocument template used in headless mode will suit your needs, as suggested [here](https://dev.to/christianca/what-tools-do-you-use-for-server-side-pdf-generation-31mb) among other solutions.